# Reusing same variables for different event Listeners

Tags: java, android

I have a few variables(edit Text and text View) and some buttons,and I want each one of the buttons do something different with the same variables. is there anyway that I won't need to define all the variables for each onClickListener? I've seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3120544/variable-onclick-listener-android) but I think my question is opposite of that!

As an example think of having a few edit text getting numbers and then some butons that do * , / ,+, - operation on them.

in addition is that possible to use results of an onCliclListener in another one? How?

Comment: Not clear. Put some example in your question.

Comment: I need to use the action result of one on click listener in the other listeners. should I do all the calculations in new listener as well or I can define them once and use everywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement onClickListener in your activity.

Declare your variables as field of activity class, like

```
int x=10;
int y=20;
int result=0;
```

Set setOnClickListener(this); to each of your button.

in onClick method, do following:

```
public void onClick(View view)
{

    if(view == btn1)
    {
       result=x+y;
    }
    if(view == btn2)
    {
       result=y-x;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Ahmad - You could also add Tags to your views, and do things based on the tags. Structure would be very similar. If you add an `int` field to your tags, you could make a `switch` statement based on that.

Comment: @Peter - Thanks peter, can you explain more.